# Problems compiling and running Java app with Bluecove (NoClassDefFoundError)

Tags: java, ubuntu, noclassdeffounderror, bluecove

I have this app that uses bluetooth, so I need both, bluecove and bluecove-gpl packages, when I run it in NetBeans I have no problem at all, and works perfectly fine. But I still can't compile and run from the command line (Ubuntu 11.04).

I'm using this line for compilation:

`$ javac -Xlint:unchecked -classpath bluecove-2.1.0.jar:bluecove-gpl-2.1.0.jar Client.java`

And it doesn't return errors and it generates a .class file

Then I try to run the .class file like this:

`java -classpath bluecove-2.1.0.jar:bluecove-gpl-2.1.0.jar Client`

But it returns a `NoClassDefFoundError`.
Could not find the main class: `SPPClient`.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add your *current* directory (or whatever directory *your* class files reside in) to the class path.

Try something like

```
java -classpath .:bluecove-2.1.0.jar:bluecove-gpl-2.1.0.jar Client
```

or

```
java -classpath bin:bluecove-2.1.0.jar:bluecove-gpl-2.1.0.jar Client
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the main class definition in the manifest file:

```
Main-Class: classname
```